# Issue with checked() echoing on to page

Tags: widgets, wp-admin

This is kind of a weird one.  I'm in the process of building a widget that goes through posts of type `product` and displays a list of checkboxes in the admin panel to display/show the products in the widgets.

Everything seems to be working fine, except the `checked()` function is not only adding the `checked='checked'` but it is also displaying it on the page.  Below is the `form` section of my widget:

```
function form( $instance ) {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => __('Featured Products', 'pp') ) );
    $title = $instance['title'];
    $products = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'post_count' => -1 ) );
  ?>
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">
        <?php _e('Title:', 'mp') ?>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($title); ?>" />
      </label>

      <?php while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post(); $prod = get_the_id();?>
      <?php
          $sku = get_post_meta($prod, 'sku', true);
          $sku = $sku[0];
          $$sku = isset($instance[$sku]) ? checked( (bool)$instance[$sku], true ) :false; 
      ?>

    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php echo $$sku; ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id($sku); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name($sku); ?>" value="1" />
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id($sku); ?>"><?php echo _e( the_title() ); ?></label><br />

      <?php endwhile; 
        wp_reset_query();
       ?>
    </p>
  <?php
  }
```

When you go into the widgets meta box in the admin panel the items that are checked and saved display as (Please note that the `[]` represents the checkbox itself):

```
checked='checked'[] Product
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
             checked='checked'
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" checked="checked" id="widget-fsol_featured_products_widget-2-WM3987HW" name="widget-featured_product_widget[2][W8DIW2]" value="1">
<label for="widget-featured_product_widget-2-W8DIW2">W8DIW2</label>
```

I've tried several different 'fixes' with no luck.  Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `checked` echoes. If you set the (currently empty) third parameter to `false`, it should work as expected.  Change the line to:

```
$$sku = isset( $instance[$sku] ) ? checked( (bool) $instance[$sku], true, false ) : false;
```

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked

Comment: Wow that was a bonehead move, I wasn't reading the documentation correctly on the subject in regards to the `$echo` param.  Thank you @SeventhSteel!  All is well!

Comment: I'd vote you up but I'm not quit there yet for Rep.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.